# Origen de la expresión "erre que erre"

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Como me ha pasado en otras ocasiones, el otro día escuché la expresión *erre que erre* y automáticamente me entró la curiosidad por conocer su origen. Por supuesto, se me pasó por la cabeza que algo tendría que ver con la letra erre, pero cuando finalmente pude consultar el diccionario, me llevé una sorpresa:

> **[erre<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=G3rSd3t)**
>
> `Quizá acort. del ár. hisp.`*`ḥírr úmmak`*`'la vulva de tu madre', interjección de los arrieros moriscos.`
>
> **erre que erre**
>   Tb. **herre que herre**, *And.*, p. us.
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Porfiadamente, tercamente.

No salía de mi asombro al pensar que al usar la expresión (recordemos, para indicar que algo se hace con insistencia y cabezonería) en realidad estamos haciendo alusión a los órganos reproductivos de la madre de nuestro interlocutor, y que la expresión no tiene nada que ver con la letra del abecedario.

En todo caso, leo que el origen se pone en duda. He intentado buscar otros orígenes pero la expresión no aparece en el *Corominas* abreviado, y el NTLLE por el motivo que sea está caído. Sí que veo que sus primeros usos son de mediados del siglo XVII:

> *Sacó doña Terencia la cara, clamando furiosa: "¡arre, arre!", y los caballos erre que erre.*
>
> Baptista Remiro de Navarra, "Los peligros de Madrid", 1646 (España).

En todo caso, ¿existen otras etimologías posibles para el *erre* de la expresión? ¿Hay casos anteriores a este?

Comment: Según el arabista Federico Corriente, esa es la etimología correcta. Lo menciona de pasada en su reciente discurso de ingreso en la RAE: https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Discurso_ingreso_Federico_Corriente.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'm not at all sure of this answer, but I'll share my idea to see what you and others think.

We know there is a pattern *X que X*, where X is some verb in the subjunctive.  One can throw this pattern into a sentence and it's a colorful way of indicating a lot of repetition of the verb.  Here are some examples:

> "El niño está llore que llore (llorando mucho) porque no le he
>   comprado ese juguete" ([source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/llore-que-llore.3026426/))
>
> De pequeña pasaba las horas hable que hable frente a un espejo
>   ([source](http://wvw.nacion.com/proa/2008/febrero/24/proa1430675.html))
>
> Efectos positivos de andar camine que camine ([source](https://habitolicious.com/2013/07/23/efectos-positivos-de-andar-camine-que-camine/))

What if *erre que erre* came from this pattern, for the verb *errar*?

Here are the relevant definitions of *errar* from DLE:

> 1 *intr.* Errar EN la respuesta.
>
> 3 *intr.* Andar vagando de una parte a otra.

Your 17th century example seems to sort of fit both:

> Sacó doña Terencia la cara, clamando furiosa: "¡arre, arre!", y los
>   caballos erre que erre.

The horses could have been both screwing up and also wandering aimlessly, at the same time.  If they did that in an extended way, then the pattern *X que X* seems to fit.

I'm sorry, I have nothing to contribute with regard to earlier documented examples.